# C++ how to trace down reason for code not saturating CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I have a multi-threaded c++ application running on Windows 10 on a system with two Xeon SP gold CPUs and 160gb of ram. The application spins up `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` many worker threads and processes data. However, at some point in the processing pipeline my CPU load as reported in task manager on all cores goes way down (to like 2-5%). After a few hours, that part of the pipeline finishes properly but I'm trying to track down the reason why the CPU cores aren't fully utilised.

This section of the code has no disk (or other) I/O and only operates on data already in memory (the memory is distributed across two NUMA nodes, but I already divided the worker threads into two groups and assigned affinity masks to each with only the cpu cores of either node set and there is very little memory that is accessed by more than one thread, but that didn't improve performance at all), task manager does not report any hard pagefaults and there are only few synchronization points.

I already started to instrument the execution, but so far my traces don't show anything suspicious, all threads seem to perform work, it's just pretty slow and task manager shows the cores being mostly idle.

So the only things I can think of so far are:

- some mutex locking somewhere in the code I'm not aware of
- very slow heap allocations due to fragmentation or something else (the application runs on a machine with 160gb physical ram and has about 90gb of working set memory)
- soft pagefaults/TLB misses (not reported by task manager) or some NUMA related issue
- something very obvious that I'm simply overlooking (most likely case)

My application links in a couple of static libraries and compiles into a single exe. I'm compiling it with MSVC (but I don't have a Visual Studio project, I'm building using Bazel).

What can I do to track this problem down and find out where and why the threads are going to sleep?

//Edit: As the comments suggested to add some code to the question so it doesn't get closed, this is the thread management (though I'm pretty sure the problem is not in here)

```
class ThreadedRunner {
 public:
  ThreadedRunner()
      : is_running_(true),
        func_(nullptr),
        barrier_(nullptr),
        count_(0),
        thread_(&ThreadedRunner::ThreadFunc, this) {}

  ~ThreadedRunner() {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
      is_running_ = false;
      condvar_.notify_all();
    }
    thread_.join();
  }

  bool Run(std::function<void(int)>* func, absl::Barrier* barrier,
           int thread_index, int thread_count, int count) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (func_ != nullptr) {
      return false;
    }
    func_ = func;
    barrier_ = barrier;
    thread_index_ = thread_index;
    thread_count_ = thread_count;
    count_ = count;
    lock.unlock();
    condvar_.notify_all();
    return true;
  }

  std::thread& MutableThread() { return thread_; }

 private:
  void ThreadFunc() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    while (true) {
      // Wait for an incoming task.
      while (is_running_ && func_ == nullptr) {
        condvar_.wait(lock);
      }
      if (!is_running_) {
        return;
      }
      assert(func_ != nullptr);

      // Execute!
      lock.unlock();
      for (int i = thread_index_; i < count_; i += thread_count_) {
        (*func_)(i);
      }

      absl::Barrier* previous_barrier = barrier_;
      // Mark this ThreadedRunner as available for another task before blocking on the current barrier.
      barrier_ = nullptr;
      thread_index_ = 0;
      thread_count_ = 0;
      count_ = 0;
      func_ = nullptr;
      if (previous_barrier->Block()) delete previous_barrier;

      lock.lock();
    }
  }

  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::condition_variable condvar_;
  bool is_running_;
  std::function<void(int)>* func_;
  absl::Barrier* barrier_;
  int thread_index_;
  int thread_count_;
  int count_;
  std::thread thread_;
};

class ThreadedRunnerPool {
 public:
  ThreadedRunnerPool() {
    ULONG highest_node_number;
    GetNumaHighestNodeNumber(&highest_node_number);
    printf("highest NUMA node: %lu\n", highest_node_number);
    num_numa_nodes_ = highest_node_number + 1;
    runners_.resize(num_numa_nodes_);
  }

  void Run(int thread_count, int count, std::function<void(int)>* func) {
    absl::Barrier* barrier = new absl::Barrier(thread_count + 1);
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

      int started = 0;
      std::vector<int> index_per_numa_node(num_numa_nodes_, 0);
      while (started < thread_count) {
        int numaIdx = started % num_numa_nodes_;
        int& idx = index_per_numa_node[numaIdx];
        if (idx >= runners_[numaIdx].size()) {
          ThreadedRunner* runner = new ThreadedRunner();
          if(num_numa_nodes_ > 1) {
            std::thread& thread = runner->MutableThread();
            unsigned char node = static_cast<unsigned char>(numaIdx);
            unsigned long long processorMask;
            GetNumaNodeProcessorMask(node, &processorMask);
            printf("node %u processor mask: %llx\n", (unsigned int) node, processorMask);
            SetThreadAffinityMask(thread.native_handle(), processorMask);
          }
          runners_[numaIdx].emplace_back(runner);
        }
        if (runners_[numaIdx][idx]->Run(func, barrier, started, thread_count, count)) {
          ++started;
        }
        ++idx;
      }
    }

    if (barrier->Block()) delete barrier;
  }

 private:
  std::mutex mutex_;
  size_t num_numa_nodes_;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ThreadedRunner>>> runners_;
};

void ParallelFor(int thread_count, int count, std::function<void(int)> func) {
  static ThreadedRunnerPool* s_Pool = new ThreadedRunnerPool();
  s_Pool->Run(thread_count, count, &func);
}
```

**Update:**

I have now globally replaced the `new` and `delete` operators (as well as `new[]` and `delete[]`) to include these calls in my profiling traces and I see now the execution time is dominated by some very long new and delete calls, several hundred milliseconds each. What can be the cause of this? heap fragmentation? if so, how to combat it? I'm already trying to preallocate memory wherever possible.

**Update#2:**

Attaching the tool recommended by @mpoeter also shows that my worker threads are stuck for more than 90% of the time in a synchronizing state inside either `ucrtbase.dll!_malloc_base` or `ucrtbase.dll!_free_base` so it looks like heap allocations and deallocations are being very slow. Any idea what could be the cause for this?

Comment: On what operating system? With Linux that might be easier, using e.g. [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). Also consider showing some [mre] in your question. Without more details, it is not clear.

Comment: The question is interesting, but you might include some example code, just to make sure no one will close it as "looking for a recommendation of a tool" or similar reason.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch running on Windows 10

Comment: @pptaszni I would like to do that but I wouldn't even know where to start or what parts of code to paste. This is a huge software project. I can paste in the code of the thread runners, but I'm pretty sure the problem is not there

Comment: What's the purpose of such a complicated logic. Why don't u just use OpenMP instead. Do you cleanup runners after upon they finished?

Comment: no, runners sleep on the condition variable until a new task is assigned. But I confirmed that during the runtime of my app there are only ever 48 threadrunners created ( on the system with 48 logical cores). Why so complicated - that's how the software project was built and this parallelization logic has worked very well so far. Porting everything over to OpenMP would probably be much more difficult than tracking this problem down, and if the problem is not in this parallelization logic then going to OpenMP won't help with it either.

Comment: @DeedeeMegadoodoo yep, Run blocks until the ParallelFor has been completed - but the slow part is during a single ParallelFor execution. The main difference (I guess) of the function I'm parallelizing compared to other functions that parallelize very well and saturate the cores is that it allocates and uses a lot more memory

Comment: Have you tried sampling stack traces while in good vs bad state? Might give a hint what's going on. How does machine health look in general, especially for nonvoluntary context switches, page faults, and swap usage?

Comment: @bobah sampling the stack traces shows that the problem are heap allocations and deallocations. How can I track involuntary context switches and soft page faults on Windows? The task manager does only show hard page faults (of which there are 0/s reported, so unless that metric is incorrect, it's probably at least not related to the page file). I do suspect TLB misses though, but I don't know how to track those.

Comment: Looks like you have a few gigabytes to spare :) Could you create separate heaps for each thread so that they don't wait on each other? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapcreate, this option looks promising: `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE`

Comment: @VladFeinstein you mean creating global replacements for new and delete and instead of malloc use these HeapAlloc on separate heaps based on current thread?

Comment: @user1282931 - yes, something like that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc + placement `new`. To avoid massive changes, you can only do it if you know that this thread is going to cause a slowdown.

Comment: @VladFeinstein but if I understand this correctly, a delete must then happen on the heap on which memory was allocated - but when replacing new and delete I can't rely on all memory being deleted only by the same threads that allocated it, so I would still need to keep track on which pointer is allocated in which heap in some dictionary, which I would need to mutex-lock in order to write to...

Comment: @user1282931 - then I should withdraw my suggestion. My point was to avoid synchronization by NOT sharing those heaps, and it appears that it was a contention point

Comment: @VladFeinstein the idea is good - I just don't fully see through how to do it. on 64bit system, there is 16terrabyte of virtual memory space. If I could define for each thread heap which address range to use, then I could simply compute the heap to delete from based on the value of a pointer address. But I don't find anything in the documentation that would allow me to specify which address range to use for a new heap

Comment: @user1282931 - as soon as you allow a second thread to access you heap, you can no longer use `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` flag, so you are loosing all benefits of separate heaps, I believe. Can't you make sure that the memory is always freed by the thread that allocated it?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I'm not using HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE because it still can happen occasionally that some object gets freed by a different thread than the one that created it. However, creating a separate heap for each thread really solved the performance problem - and by using thread_local storage I don't need a mutex to synchronize access

Comment: Read the  [Garbage collection handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) - it should give you some insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer since I was able to solve the problem by creating a separate heap for each thread. I'm using thread_local storage to track heap handles, so I don't need a mutex to synchronize access (I'm not using HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE for the heaps though since it's still possible that threads might delete objects created by other threads, in which case it might be possible that multiple threads access the same heap), but using this code my cpu utilization goes from like 2% up to full 100% and instead of having to wait a day for my pipeline to finish it completes in under an hour. I guess the Windows 10 heap is not optimized for lots of large allocations from many threads. Anyway, happy with the solution:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

    thread_local HANDLE heap_handle_;

    const char* LastSystemErrorText() {
        static char err[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPWSTR)err, 255, NULL);
        return err;
    }

    HANDLE CreateNewHeap() {
        HANDLE handle = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);
        if (handle == NULL) {
            printf("Error: could not create large object heap: %s\n",
                LastSystemErrorText());
        }
        return handle;
    }

    inline bool heap_free(HANDLE handle, void* ptr) {
        bool success = HeapFree(handle, 0, ptr);
        if (!success) {
            printf("Failed to free memory: %s\n", LastSystemErrorText());
        }
        return success;
    }

    inline void* new_impl(std::size_t req_bytes) {
        // Allocate additional bytes to store which heap the memory was allocated in.
        size_t sz = req_bytes + sizeof(HANDLE);
        if (heap_handle_ == NULL) {
            heap_handle_ = CreateNewHeap();
        }
        void* ptr = HeapAlloc(heap_handle_, 0, sz);
        if (ptr) {
            *((HANDLE*)ptr) = heap_handle_;
            return (void*)(((char*)ptr) + sizeof(HANDLE));
        }
        else {
            throw std::bad_alloc{};
        }
    }

    inline void delete_impl(void* ptr) {
        if (!ptr)
            return;
        void* actual_ptr = (void*)(((char*)ptr) - sizeof(HANDLE));
        HANDLE heap_handle = *((HANDLE*)actual_ptr);
        heap_free(heap_handle, actual_ptr);
    }
}  // namespace

// globally replacing operators new and delete

void* operator new(std::size_t sz) {
    return new_impl(sz);
}

void* operator new[](std::size_t sz) {
    return new_impl(sz);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    delete_impl(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept
{
    delete_impl(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you are using Bazel, but you still might want to give the profiling tools in Visual Studio a try (the Community version is sufficient for that). I would start with a simple sampling run. For more details you can install the [Concurrency Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConcurrencyVisualizer2019) addon. With the concurrency visualizer you get much more insight (like which thread is waiting for a lock + which thread is holding the lock an for how long). However, capturing all this data results in very big files, so your concurrency runs should only capture data for a few minutes max. The more threads you have, the more data, so you might want to keep an eye on the trace file and stop profiling once it reaches 1GB, otherwise processing the file is almost impossible (at least that was the case in previous studio versions).

For both, sampling and concurrency runs, you can start the binary you have built with Bazel and simply attach the Visual Studio profiler to the existing process.

Comment: What a wonderfully beautiful tool! thank you very much!! It looks like my worker threads are for the majority of the time stuck in synchronization inside either `ucrtbase.dll!_malloc_base` or `ucrtbase.dll!_free_base` so the problem is definitely related to the heap. any idea what can be done about this?

Answer (score -1):

There are tools that may help you. On linux perf uses hardware counters and interrupts to see which functions have performance problems.

Ftrace and Strace will let you see what is happening with things like mutexes blocking.

L

Briefly looking at the code posted are running _func in a mutex. This will block other threads running while it executes. For maximal performance only lock for a short time.

Comment: thank you! is there anything similar that works on Windows too? Only the assignment of a new task to the threadrunners is locked with the mutex, not the execution

Comment: Simple idea is let it run in the debugger and stop it at random and see what your threads are up to.